# I can't install or update any extensions in Visual Studio Code.The error is [error] Untrusted: Signature

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't install or update any extensions in Visual Studio Code.

The error is

```
[error] Untrusted: Signature: Untrusted
    at yt.download (vscode-file://vscode-app/d:/anzhuang/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:91:468)
    at async X.x (vscode-file://vscode-app/d:/anzhuang/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:91:20760)
    at async X.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/d:/anzhuang/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:91:18897)
```

But I can now manually install the extensions， using VSIX document.

i use vscode on windows10.

how can i solve this problem？

I closed all my proxy. And i also disable "proxy strict SSL" in vscode. but nothing works.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/164726 (that problem is supposed to be fixed now though). In any case, what happens if you set `"extensions.verifySignature": false` in your user settings file (and remote settings file if you are connecting to VS Code via remote) and then completely restart VS Code by closing and reopening it?

Comment: @starball nothing good happens